# How to keep two dataset(grouping on each dataset) on one page

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement on which i need to show calender for each month with days on it and below this i need to show count for different services for that particular month. For this i have created two datasets
1> For the calender one 
2> Different services for each month. Now I am not sure how to keep these two data sets on one page means
suppose its january month, so i need to show the calender for the January month and the total sevices for january month on one page and in the second page it will be show these two for februray month and it will go on. The number of months is controlled by a parameter .

What i have done now ?
For the 1st dataset the group is there and i have put page break after the group. And for the 2nd dataset, i have the group and put a page break after the group.

Please suggest how can i put these datasets on one page ( both are having group on the basis of month).

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Subrat

Comment: I would use a sub report. Create a report that just handles 1 month and accepts a month as a parameter. Then create the 'master' report. This will only need a dataset that lists months, a tablix bound to the dataset and then insert a subreport onto the detail row. If you don;t know how to do this, search SO you'll find answers or ask here and I will post a full answer.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for this. But my requirement is client have the ability to provide the number of month. If client provides 3 months ( user has the ability to select the first month) then 3 months record should display.Now i am able to fetch all the records but its breaking in 6 pages, all reports are separated, i need each month's report should display on a page , so 3 months reports should display in 3 pages.

Comment: I've added a full solution,. Don't be put off by the length of it, it's really quite easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example.

**NOTE:** I'm using the AdventureWorks sample database here..

First we create the subreport. This will be a standard report but it will only produce results for a single month in our case. In this example I only pass in the month number as a parameter but obviously you might need to change that to pass in a year and/or other information.

I created a new report called `Month Sub Report`
I created two datasets that will give me sales by person and sales by territory for the same month. The queries I used are as follows.

```
-- query for dsSalesByPerson
  select MONTH(OrderDate) as MonthNumber, SalesPersonID, p.LoginID , SUM(TotalDue) as Amount 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader s 
    join HumanResources.Employee p on s.SalesPersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
  where datepart(yy, OrderDate) = 2013
  and MONTH(OrderDate) = @MonthNumber
  GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate), SalesPersonID, p.LoginID

-- query for dsSalesByTerritory  
select MONTH(OrderDate) as MonthNumber, t.Name as Terrotory , SUM(TotalDue) as Amount 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader s 
    join sales.Customer c on s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    join sales.SalesTerritory t on c.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID
where datepart(yy, OrderDate) = 2013
and MONTH(OrderDate) = @MonthNumber
GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate), t.name
```

**Note** These both use the same parameter name with the EXACT same spelling, including case. As the create the datasets the parameter will be automatically created. If the name is the same on both databasets, only 1 parameter will be created which is what we want.

Next I added two simple tables and a textbox that looks like a header (actual headers don't work in subreports)

The final design looked like this.

[image]

When I run the subreport I get something like this.

[image]

Save and close this report design....

Next, create a new report, in this example I called it `Month Master Report`.

I created dataset called `dsMonths` with a list of months in (MonthNumber and MonthName) that we will use in our main report parameter to allow users to chose the months they want to report on.

I set the available values to point to our dsMonths dataset query and set it to allow multiple values (leave type as text)

Next create another dataset called `dsMain`. The query for this dataset needs to return a unique list of  monthnumbers from your database so it might look something like

```
select DISTINCT MONTH(OrderDate) as MonthNumber 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader s 
where datepart(yy, OrderDate) = 2013
and MONTH(OrderDate) IN (@Months)
ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate)
```

**Note:** We use IN here as we are passing a list of @Months in.

Next, insert a table

Set the Dataset property og the table to `dsMain`

Next, remove the header row and all the column except 1.

Your table should have just a single 'cell' remaining. In this cell, right-click and insert a subreport.

Right-click the sub-report placeholder and choose properties.

Set the subreport used to be your subreport created earlier (i.e. `Month Sub Report`)

Click the parameters tab and then click "Add". Choose "MonthNumber" from under the name dropdown and your monthnumber fields from the value drop down list.

[image]

Next, double-click the "(Details)" row group nuder the main design window, click "Page Breaks" and select "Between each instance"

FINALLY!  Mover the table to the top left corner of the page and shirk the report body so there is not lots of space around it (or this can cause unexpected page breaks)

When we run the report and choose a few Months we get the following, with each selected month on a new page (I'm only showing the last page in this image)

[image]

Hopefully that will give you enough to solve your issue.